# Как сформировать запрос на комплексное удаление записей в Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, delete

Из определенной таблицы в базе PostgreSql необходимо удалить несколько записей по определенному перечню первичных ключей. Если первичным ключем является одна колонка, я могу сформировать запрос:

```
DELETE FROM "USERS" WHERE "Id" IN
('a541a658-07b5-11e6-971e-005056887b8d',
'b03c2215-c430-11e5-8478-005056887b8d',
'a783c055-ec2e-11e5-899e-005056887b8d',
'ad253abd-ace7-11e7-ba66-005056b2fc3d',
'b139d9ef-39d7-11e9-acea-005056b24375',
'bb6ab30a-7cb8-11e5-b6f7-005056887b8d');
```

Как сформировать комплексный запрос на удаление, если в первичный ключ входит несколько колонок?
например "Name", "Phone", "Adress"?
И будет ли такое удаление более быстрым, по сравнению с отдельными запросами на каждую запись?

Comment: Спасибо. Перенеси пожалуйста в отдельный ответ, чтобы я мог его отметить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE ("Name", "Phone", "Adress") IN ( ('Name1', 'Phone1', 'Adress1'), 
                                       ('Name2', 'Phone2', 'Adress2'), 
                                       ...
                                     )
```